# ClassLoader loading the wrong instance of a file

Tags: java, classloader, inputstream

So I see there has already been a post very similar to this issue, however I am in a situation where I have no power to specify the location of this file within my jar and so am hoping someone is aware of a solution to get around this.

So I currently use the following snippet to obtain a file as an input stream, the file 'plugin.xml' is located at the root of the jar and I cannot change this location as another piece of software (dynatrace) creates this file and determines its location.

the standard snippet:

`InputStream is = JmxPlugin.class.getResourceAsStream("/plugin.xml");`

Now I am aware that the issue is that the ClassLoader is picking up the first file which matches the name 'Plugin.xml' along the classpath (one which isn't in my jar, yay).

Can anyone think of a way to ensure I pick up the correct file without having to move it? The relative path of my class in the jar is com/something/jmx/JmxPlugin.class.

(Id rather not have to unpack the jar in memory).

Many thanks for any contributions,

Comment: I'm confused by your wording. If your file is located within your jar at the root of the path and you use "plugin.xml", then that is the path you need to use in your call. If it's in the foo package, then you need "foo/plugin.xml" - so what is the issue? If you know the location of the file you want within your jar, then just pass in the location of the file..

Comment: I can't see how my wording is unclear :S basically whats happening is: ClassLoader locates another file also called 'plugin.xml' in another jar which is on the classpath before my jar and so when it finds that one first it basically says, "oh ive found 'plugin.xml', this is the one!" and its not....

Comment: You forgot to mention that there was more than one jar involved. Reading your issue through, it sounds like you're talking about duplicate files in a single jar. Anyway, assuming both files have exactly the same path within both jars, you might be able to use ClassLoader.getResources("path/in/both/jars") which will return you an Enumeration of resources representing things that match that path. You'll then have to determine which is the right one. Failing that, you'll have to implement your own ClassLoader to solve this problem.

Comment: tried that, it only returns the wrong one, doesn't return both.

Comment: Then you need a custom ClassLoader I'm afraid. Solving problems with ClassPath conflicts has always been a pain, and I strongly recommend you come up with some other way of getting access to this file.

Comment: You might also want to try URLClassLoader and try the findResources() method on it. Never used it. Might work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure, but seems like `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/plugin.xml")` may solve your issue. If not, you'll have to create your own `ClassLoader` and resolve the issue there.

Answer (score 0):

The simplies way is to move your jar in classpath to be the first containing Plugin.xml,
Another approach is to use getResource() to locate your jar file:

```
URL myJar=JmxPlugin.class.getResource("/"+JmxPlugin.class.getName().replace(".","/")+".class");
```

then use this URL to open jar file and extract Plugin.xml.